# Python: Passing a function and calling it recursively

Tags: python, function, recursion

The goal is to pass a function and a number as arguments to another function, which then recursively calls the passed function n times. I implemented this two ways. This version works as expected, printing `Hello World` 3 times:

```
def do_n(fx, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        print(fx)
        do_n(fx, n-1)

def return_greeting():
    return "Hello World"

do_n(return_greeting(), 3)
```

This version does not work. It prints `Hello World` only once, and then seems to lose the called function after the first time through:

```
def do_n(fx, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        fx
        do_n(fx, n-1)

def print_greeting():
    print("Hello World")

do_n(print_greeting(), 3)
```

Can someone explain why the second version does not result in `print_greeting` being called 3 times and printing `Hello World` 3 times to the screen?

Comment: Can you post actual code?  `define` here would raise a `SyntaxError`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version doesn't call `print_greeting` three times -- actually, neither version does.

You call `print_greeting` exactly once, in the last line of each code snippet. In that line, you call it, and it returns the string, and you just pass the string into your `do_n` function.

You can make two changes to your second snippet to make it do what you think it should be doing:

First, *dont* call `print_greeting` in the last line. It should look like this:

```
do_n(print_greeting, 3)
```

That way, you pass the actual function `print_greeting` into your do_n function.

Second, call the passed function (now called `fx`) like this:

```
fx()
```

The parentheses here mean "call this function".

The whole snippet should look like this:

```
def do_n(fx, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        fx()
        do_n(fx, n-1)

def print_greeting():
    print("Hello World")

do_n(print_greeting, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I fixed the "working" version so that it is written as I intended, as well, based on the information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `fx` doesn't do anything. I think you meant to say `fx()` to actually call the function.

Comment: Also pass the function as `print_greeting` without parens

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, you are passing `Hello World` string to do_n function and printing n times that's why it just prints n times (actually you are not calling the function).

In the second version, you have the string but you are just declaring it..If you want to make this function really call, you have to change your code as:

```
def do_n(fx, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return
    else:
        fx()
        do_n(fx, n-1)

def return_greeting():
    print "Hello World"

do_n(return_greeting, 3)
```